# How to send the value of a windows environment variable?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a function like this:

```
Seep(toSend){
  Send, %toSend%
  Sleep, 1000
}
```

I use it like this:

```
Seep("Typing a new line{Enter}")
```

I want to send the value of a windows environment variable to that function to be printed out, like this:

```
Seep("This is the path: " %PATH% " ok now what?{Enter}")
```

I have tried many variations on this to no avail. Typically, it just prints nothing for PATH, like this:

```
This is the path:  ok now what?
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
Seep("This is the path: %PATH% ok now what?{Enter}") ; prints literally %PATH%
```

I tried putting it in a variable first:

```
pathv:=PATH  ; also tried %PATH%, $PATH with the same outcome
Seep("This is the path: " pathv " ok now what?{Enter}")  ; prints an empty string
```

I even put it in double variables:

```
pathv:=PATH
toPrint:="This is the path: " pathv " ok now what?{Enter}"
```

And again, an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the `#NoEnv`[1] directive your in script environment variables are not available.
You can use the `EnvGet`[2] command in such cases, example:

```
EnvGet, vPath, Path
MsgBox % vPath
Seep("This is the path: " vPath " ok now what?{Enter}")
```

[1] https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_NoEnv.htm
[2] https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvGet.htm